# javascript appear a thing with specific id using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html-select, appendchild

I don't know how to explain it, I don't want it to be unclear, so first thing first, I want to show this HTML code :

```
<body>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="num" onkeyup="addOptions()" name="member" id="member">
    <div id="selects">

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

And this is the javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addOptions() {
  document.getElementById('selects').innerHTML = "";
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('member').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValue; i++) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerText = "Example";

    select.appendChild(option);
    document.getElementById('selects').appendChild(select);
  }
}
</script>
```

So, groove of this code will be if I type num in input num, the select will be appear as many as I type the num. But, it just will run the select option. So, my question is can I appear that the option is in HTML code? So when I type the num in the textfield, I will appear something like this for example :

```
<option value="example" id="example">example</option>
```

So the option code will be running as many as the num, like when I type 3 in the textfield, I will get 3 code like in above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, there are some issues in your code. I believe you are trying to achieve a drop down using `select`.

Inside `for` loop you creating `select` in each iteration which I think you don't want. To make `value`, `id` avilable to the newly created `option` you have to set those properties to the `option`.

Try the following:

```js
function addOptions() {
  document.getElementById('selects').innerHTML = "";
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  var inputValue = Number(document.getElementById('member').value);
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValue; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerText = "Example" + i;
    option.value = "example" + i;
    option.id = "example" + i;
    select.append(option);
  }
  if(select.innerHTML) // if at least one option then append select
    document.getElementById('selects').appendChild(select);
}
```

```html
<input type="num" oninput="addOptions()" name="member" id="member"><br><br>
<div id="selects">

</div>
```

Comment: I thought this was what they were asking for but couldn't be sure lol

Comment: @Scath, even at first I was not sure. Then looking at OP's code, I thought he might be after this finally......thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Just move some lines out of your for loop, as following:

```js
function addOptions() {
  document.getElementById('selects').innerHTML = "";
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('member').value;
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValue; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerText = "Example "+i;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
  document.getElementById('selects').appendChild(select);
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
  <input type="num" onkeyup="addOptions()" name="member" id="member">
  <div id="selects">

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I said it with unclear. I don't want to loop the value of an option, but I want to add as many as the num. Like there are 2 options element in the web, so the user can select 2 times

Comment: @LouiseKaithlyn what is the difference between my answer and the one you have chosen? A bit funny though, because I could not really understand you anyway.